# C++ How to pass reference for this specific code?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, sum, pass-by-reference

Consider the following:

```
void sum(vector<string> arr[], vector<string> columnName)
{
    int n, *sum = 0;
    cout << "Enter column number to calculate : ";
    cin >> n;
    cin.ignore(80, '\n');
    cout << columnName[n-1] << endl;
    for (auto item=arr[n-1].begin(); item!=arr[n-1].end(); item++)
    {
        if (item[0] == "1")
        {
            for (int i=1; i<sizeof(item[n-1]); i++)
            {
                // cout << item[i] << " ";
                sum += stoi(item[i]);  //how to reference this(the sum im talking about)
                 cout << sum << " ";
            }
            cout << sum << endl; // to become value of sum outside of the block here
        }
        else
            if (item[0] == "0")
            {
                cout << "Column can not be calculated" << endl;
                break;
            }
    }
    // return sum;
}
```

with data such as:

```
7
id,age,math,science,malay,chem,bio
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
5
1201101210,19,95,98,97,90,88
1201101490,12,87,100,92,100,70
1201101154,40,98,72,78,81,94
1201101376,23,40,50,70,79,100
1201101987,36,85,73,74,66,59
```

There is a sum with local variable that I highlighted with a comment, and I want to bring that sum out from the block to the block below ( aka make the local variable global). I think this can be achieved by using pass by reference but I am unsure on how to do it :(

Comment: The code would make more sense if `sum` wasn't a pointer Try removing the star in the `int n, *sum = 0;` declaration.

Comment: There's more things that doesn't make sense, for example `sizeof(item[n-1])`. Or generally using the iterator as an array or vector. I'm also worried about your use of a pointer to a vector, instead of using a vector of vectors.

Comment: And why would you want to make the `sum` variable global? Or even pass it as a (reference) argument? Why not return it properly?

Comment: Sorry but this just plain looks weird  vector<string> arr[]... (mixing C++ idiomatic programming with "C" style arrays): why not just make it a std::vector<std::vector<std::sting>>& ? Then the problem with references are gone

Comment: All in all it looks like you're learning programming from a so-called "competition" or "online judge" site. Don't do that, such sites are *not* any kind of learning or teaching resource. In fact, using them as such could be actively harmful for your learning, as many such sites have examples that are not only bad but also invalid.